# Windows 7 Start Menu: Height does not adapt

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

Since a couple of days my start menu has a big blank space and just does not collapse.

I played around with `Store and display recently opened programs in the Start menu` as well as `Number of recent programs to display` as is depicted at [sevenforums.com](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/25776-start-menu-change-height.html). Note that doing so clears your list of recently opened programs. Anyway, my start menu still looks like:

[image]

At least the space marked with a red rectangle should collapse.

Comment: What's your *Number of recent programs to display*?

Comment: Even when i pick 1 and press Okay followed by Apply it does not change the height of my menu.

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of things I would recommend trying here:

1)HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
Change the Min_MFU value to 1
This will try and force the number of recent programs to 1 in the registry.  It is defintiely worth a try

2)System restore.  If this only happened a couple of days ago - was it after an update, software installation or similar?  You may find that a windows system restore will fix this for you.

Hope one of these helps.